# Enable Compiz Fusion at startup kde

Tags: ubuntu, kde, compiz

Compiz is "temporarily disabled" by default, I have to enable Compiz by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> every time I start my computer.

Can somebody please tell me how it can be enabled automatically at startup?

I am using Compiz Fusion on Kubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Compiz? You mean the Desktop Effects provided with KDE4 right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `compiz --replace` line in your `~/.bashrc` file, if you want to start it automatically on every login.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ATI proprietary (`fglrx`) drivers?  They seem to have problems with compositing when the system is under high load.  Such as when KDE is starting up.

If you really want to force compositing to come on at startup, then go "System Settings" > "Desktop Effects" > "Advanced" > "Disable functionality checks".  Note that this could make your system unusable if there's a driver problem, and KDE can't disable compositing to work around it.